# How to sync emails manually and calendar/contacts "as item arrive"?

Tags: 8.0, lumia, sync

I need different sync settings for emails and for calendar/contacts. I want to sync email  manually, but my calendar and contacts "as item arrive". However there is only one settings for all of them. How do I do that?
Such settings was norm at android, but I can't figure it out on WP8 (lumia 520).

Thanks for advice

Answer (score 1):

Sorry but these settings are linked to each other as you already found out yourself.

Why do you want to sync mail manually btw? if you get less then 1 mail each 30 minutes "As items arrive" uses less battery then manually syncing every 30 minutes.

Comment: Thanks. I actually receive way too many emails, but I rarely read them on my phone. I probably use the manual email sync once or twice a month in case of real necessity. Syncing them all the time eats lot of data and battery and I don't need to know there is another unread email (because there are always few). However I need the calendar up to date all the time. Even 15/30 minutes delay can be deadly sometimes.

Comment: Do you have a reference for the battery usage on that?